# How to avoid the cache or concurrency in telerik data access ORM?

Tags: caching, telerik, telerik-open-access, openaccess

Now I want to  calculate the  average concentration of pm2.5 these days in each city through stored procedure .The first input parameter of the stored procedure is cityname string like `Beijing,NewYork`,and the other input parameters are `beginTime` and `endTime`.And the output class is called AvgPM25.

```
public class AvgPM25{
public String CityName{get;set;}
public decimal AvgValue{get;set;}
}
```

I pass parameters like `Beijing,NewYork`,`20140801`,`20140802`,it calculate and output the result.Now my problem is sometimes I try to change the parameters like search time,and the input parameters are like `Beijing,NewYork`,`20130801`,`20140802`,but it still output the result which is the previous search result.Is this problem due to the cache or concurrentcy?I try to set identity of 'CityName' of the  `AvgPM25` class property to be True,and set the cache policy to be NoCache,and set the concurrency mode to be Changed but still have this problem?How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you change the search time,but the identity is not changed.Change the output class below may help you.Or you can try to set identity of the `AvgPM25` class property to be True?

```
public class AvgPM25{
//identity:true,cache:default 
public String CityName{get;set;}
public decimal AvgValue{get;set;}
//identity:true,cache:default,conbined with the two strings,like '2013080120140802'
 public string SearchTIme{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This class does not use `SearchTIme` property is a waste of time, but there is no better way I have found.